# Where is the problem: error: expected expression before ‘int

Tags: c

So, i get this error: ( `error: expected expression before ‘int’` ) and i cant seem to be able to understand the issue here.This a part of my code:

```
int **P,i,N,*A,temp,j,result,m;

// in this part the user gives the input for m,**P,N,*A, so this part of code is skipped

result = foo(int m,int N,int *A,int **P); // this is the line where the error occurs
```

Also the .h file for foo has been included

Comment: You are mixing the syntax for function declaration with function call. In a function call you only provide the arguments but don't specify types. => `result = foo(m, N, A, P);`

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post a minimal, and complete _out of the box_ example, showing the error you are getting.  Most probably the error will be in the part you have _explained, and is not shown_ due to your brevity.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you call a function in `C`, its not even a proper declaration.

> `result = foo(int m,int N,int *A,int **P);`

What you are using  is an improper function call. In C function declaration needs the type of parameters you pass when calling a function as shown below.

`int foo(int m,int N,int *A,int **P);`

But function call needs only name of the variable(s) (or address of variable(s) in case if we pass address) without their types, just pass only name of variable(s), no need of types as shown below.

`result = foo( m, N,A,P);`